# Bootstrap Grid layout good practice

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, grid-layout

I have a question about grid on part of my page, what is better practice to do, in case where I have multiple xx-12 columns in proximity, where my question is not about alignment or breakpoints but of child-parent relations of rows and cols..

```
<div class="col-xx-12">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xx-12">something</div>
<div class="col-xx-12">something</div>
<div class="col-xx-12">something</div>
</div>
</div>
```

or

```
<div class="col-xx-12">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xx-12">something</div>
</div>
<div class="row>
<div class="col-xx-12">something</div>
</div>
<div class="row>
<div class="col-xx-12">something</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First is the better option for practice because in this you don't have to repeat your part of code several time like:
* starting the class="row".

```html
 <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xx-12">something</div>
            <div class="col-xx-12">something</div>
            <div class="col-xx-12">something</div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

2nd is good for grid practice,according me & if you use 2nd type then you dont need to define

`<div class='col-xx-12'>` everytime

You can use directly like below,example

```
 <div class='col-xx-4'></div>
 <div class='col-xx-4'></div>
 <div class='col-xx-4'></div>
```

Comment: all of them alre col-xx-12..